# Need to show the data from past few days in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, mysql-workbench

```
SELECT 
  c.name, 
  ec.device_id, 
  ec.description, 
  MAX(ee.recd_time), 
  MAX(ee.error) 
FROM 
  endpoints e 
  JOIN endpoint_config ec 
    ON e.device_id = ec.device_id 
  JOIN client c 
    ON c.id = ec.client_id 
  JOIN endpoint_error ee 
    ON e.id = ee.endpoint_id 
WHERE 
  c.name = "ABCD" 
  AND (ee.recd_time between '2022-06-21' AND '2022-06-24') 
  AND ee.error LIKE "%switch%" 
GROUP BY 
  ec.device_id;
```

When I'm using the above command, I'm unable to fetch the last 3 days data.

Is the query incorrect? Please help me

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. I'm afraid, I have no idea what table or table data you are operating on. Furthermore: Are you getting any sort of error message? Or simply 'unexpected results'?

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question). Realistically it's very difficult to answer a SQL question without seeing some sample data and expected results. Remember we've never seen your schema or your data. And what does "unable to" actually mean in practice? Explain what you expected to see and what actually happened instead - is there an error, or just the wrong results, or what? See also [ask] and the [tour] for more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: If its an error this might be wrong `"%switch%"` instead try `'%switch%'`  (single quotes)

Comment: Does `ee.recd_time >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY` in place of your BETWEEN clause work for you?

Comment: **Pro tip** be fanatical about formatting your SQL so it's readable.  One line SQL isn't.   **Pro tip** pay close attention to error messages or incorrect results, and if you ask for help, show them.